# jQuery hover fadein/fadeout/slidetoggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I onhover I can get the effect what I need, but when I move the mouse to "my list" `a` tag, `#bb` div disappeared. how could I make it stays there as I need to click it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="aa">click</div>
<div id="bb"> <a href="">my list</a></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#bb').hide();
$('#aa').hover(function(){
    $('#bb').slideToggle();
});
```

Online sample here - http://jsfiddle.net/9tjZK/

Comment: `a{background:transparent;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/9tjZK/7/.**

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="aa">click</div>
<div id="bb"> <a href="">my list</a></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#bb').hide();
$('#aa').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#bb').fadeIn();
});

$('#container').mouseleave(function(){
   $('#bb').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your HTML, so the anchor is inside the element where you bound the mouseenter/leave event :

```
<div id="aa">click
    <div id="bb"> 
        <a href="">my list</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9tjZK/5/)

Comment: this works perfectly. I always use this way.. you dont need to write extra code

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="aa">click</div>
    <div id="bb"> <a href="">my list</a></div>
</div>
```

and jQuery code:

```
$('#bb').hide();

$("#wrapper").hover(
  function () {
    $('#bb').stop(true, true).slideDown();
  },
  function () {
    $('#bb').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
  }
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9tjZK/9/

Answer (score 0):

olo, you can try using on click event than hover, this gives you the desired results.

`you can check here http://jsfiddle.net/9tjZK/8/`